# Using Python, how to you catch MySQL LOCK errors but raise all others?

Tags: python, mysql, locking, try-catch

I'm doing some work using Python to update a MySQL database. Many instances of my script can be running at one time, so occasionally I will get LOCK error messages from the MySQL server:

*mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction*

If these occur, I would like to retry the operation. I can use a basic **except Exception as e** statement, but that traps all errors, which is not what I need.

How can I trap only the LOCK errors generated by MySQL?

```
cursor = mysql.connector.connect(host="myhost.com", user=username, passwd=password, db=schema, auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

sql = "UPDATE table SET mycolumn = 'mydata'"

while True:
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        break
    except Exception as e:   # I only want to catch LOCK errors here
        print(repr(e))

    except:
        print(sql)
        raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the error code and perform certain actions based on it. An example for the `pymysql` module, for yours - refer to the documentation.

```
import pymysql
from pymysql.err import DatabaseError

try:
    mydb = pymysql.connect(
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        port = 123123,
        user = "user id",
        password = "!!!!!!!"
        )
except DatabaseError as e:
    err_code = e.args[0]
    if err_code == 2003:
        print('bad connection string')
    else:
        raise
```

Output:

```
bad connection string
```

Answer (score 0):

the error number is 1205

So catch the this number

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

cursor = mysql.connector.connect(host="myhost.com", user=username, passwd=password, db=schema, auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

sql = "UPDATE table SET mycolumn = 'mydata'"

while True:
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        break
        if err.errno == 1205 :
            print("Lock wait timeout exceeded")
        else:
            print(sql)
            raise
```

Comment: Where is the `except`? Some cute thing with `try` `break`?

Comment: you don't need it as i have show in my answer

Comment: How does the exception magically jump over the break and stop at if? Execute throws and the existence of a break means make a landing pad for the exception there and goto the line after the break in the landing pad? Or what?